# How to create the equivalent of a HashMap<Int, Int[]> in Lua

Tags: data-structures, dictionary, lua, redis, hashmap

I would like to have a simple data structure in lua resembling a Java HashMap equivalent.

The purpose of this is that I wish to maintain a unique key 'userID' mapped against a set of two values which get constantly updated, for example;

```
'77777', {254, 24992}
```

Any suggestions as to how can I achieve this?

---

```
-- Individual Aggregations
local dictionary = ?

-- Other Vars
local sumCount = 0
local sumSize = 0
local matches = redis.call(KEYS, query)

for _,key in ipairs(matches) do
    local val = redis.call(GET, key)
    local count, size = val:match(([^:]+):([^:]+))

    topUsers(string.sub(key, 11, 15), sumCount, sumSize)

    -- Global Count and Size for the Query
    sumCount = sumCount + tonumber(count)
    sumSize = sumSize + tonumber(size)
end

local result = string.format(%s:%s, sumCount, sumSize)
return result;

-- Users Total Data Aggregations
function topUsers()
  -- Do sums for each user
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that dictionary is what you are asking about:

```
local dictionary = {
    ['77777'] = {254, 24992},
    ['88888'] = {253, 24991},
    ['99999'] = {252, 24990},
}
```

The tricky part is that the key is a string that can't be converted to a Lua variable name so you must surround each key with `[]`. I can't find a clear description of rule for this in [Lua 5.1 reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html), but the [Lua wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial) says that if a key "consists of underscores, letters, and numbers, but doesn't start with a number" only then does it not require the `[]` when defined in the above manner, otherwise the square brackets are required.

Comment: tried this
    private static final String READ_SCRIPT_IN_LUA = 
"local dictionary = {"+
" ['77777'] = {254, 24992},"+
"['88888'] = {253, 24991},"+
"['99999'] = {252, 24990}"+
"}"+
"  return dictionary";
Object o = jedis.eval(String.format(READ_SCRIPT_IN_LUA));
System.out.println(o.toString());
Output : []
am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Lua table indexed by userID and with values another Lua table with two entries:

```
T['77777']={254, 24992}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible implementation of the solution.

```
local usersTable = {}

function topUsers(key, count, size)
    if usersTable[key] then
        usersTable[key][1] = usersTable[key][1] + count
        usersTable[key][2] = usersTable[key][2] + size
    else
        usersTable[key] = {count, size}
    end
end

function printTable(t)
    for key,value in pairs(t) do 
        print(key, value[1], value[2])
    end
end
```